# one person winning 5 tickets odds

Tags: probability

In a raffle with 90 tickets, 9 people buy 10 tickets each. There are 5 winning tickets which are drawn at random.

Find the probability that one person gets all 5 winning tickets?

P(person A wins 1st ticket) = $\frac{10}{90}$

P(person A wins 2nd ticket) =$ \frac{9}{89}$

P(person A wins 3rd ticket) =$ \frac{8}{88}$

P(person A wins 4th ticket) =$ \frac{7}{87}$

P(person A wins 5th ticket) =$ \frac{6}{86}$

Would the probability be:
$$\frac{10}{90}*\frac{9}{89}*\frac{8}{88}*\frac{7}{87}*\frac{6}{86}  $$

This is giving me a very low probability which makes me believe is wrong. How could i answer this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You evaluate the probability that $A$ gets all the winning tickets, but you want the probability that someone has the 5 winning tickets. You need to multiply by $9$.
$$9\times\frac{10}{90}\times\frac{9}{89}\times\frac{8}{88}\times\frac{7}{87}\times\frac{6}{86}$$

Comment: could the probability then be 0.0000516050? Seems very low

Comment: @Daniel It seems low, but it is right. Let's see it this way. The first drawing isn't important (since it could be anyone). For the second drawing, it need to be the same winner, his probability is less than $\frac19$. His probability to keep winning will decrease with each drawing. So the probability that someone wins the 5 drawings is less than$9^{-4}=0.00015\ldots$. Our value is smaller than this and relatively close to it. It does make sense.